# import org.yaml cannot be resolved error

Tags: java

If anyone has any experience working with Yaml (.yml extension files), I could use some assistance. I am trying to write a little program that reads .yml files from a folder I made on my desktop.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml

public class readYaml {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
        try (InputStream in = readYaml.class.getResourceAsStream("/Collections.yml")) {
            Question question = yaml.loadAs(in, Question.class);
            System.out.println(question);
        }
    }

}
```

*EDIT*
 I created a resources folder in my project file in response to an error on line 8 stating "This is coming from an error I am getting from an error I am getting on line 8, stating "The import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml cannot be resolved"", but now I am getting this error. I think it will be best explained in screen shots. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVD2c.png)

and this happens on my project folder
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wG05L.png)

I hope this makes things clearer to understand.

Comment: Your error is related with your project structure, you probably didn't add the YAML JAR file into your classpath. Also, besides that you say that you are trying to open a yml file that is in your desktop and you are using `getResourceAsStream` this will likely end in a FileNotFoundException.

Comment: Oops. Clumsy mistake on my end. I'm a beginner and I was just following along with a tutorial, and I didn't take having my folder on my desktop into consideration. Should I just make a separate folder for yml files in my project directory??

Comment: Since you are using resource as stream add your yml files into the resources folder of your project or if you are not using a maven project put then into your classes package.

Comment: Added my yml files to recourses folder inside of the project. I guess I am still incorrectly adding yml files to the class path. I've searched and tried several suggestions but every time I get a red exclamation point over the project folder with a pop up messaging saying  "JavaBuilder on project YAMLParser. java.lang.NullPointerException."

Comment: Things have changed then, you have now another error, which is good. So add to your question how is your project setup so we can understand it and also, point out at your code where (in which line) the NullPointerException is coming from.

Comment: None of those screenshots helps in anything, so avoid it in the future here at SO. You are using eclipse so open the problem and errors TAB and look there what the error is. In Windows you can go to Window->Show View-Markers, Then again to go Other (same menu) and select errors and also problems. Don't know if they are in the same place on mac os.

Comment: Okay thank you for the feedback. I have seen other screenshots in posts so I thought that would help. I was able to get the issue resolved! Thanks for your patience and help!